# Stored procedure returning 1

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, crossbar

I am not able to understand that why is stored procedure is returning Allow = 1 in the result set. I have edited to add more context to the the questions basically this stored procedure does authorization based on the result, if the result set is say Allow:0, Disclose: 1, Cache:1, corresponding  URI's is not registered however if the  result set is say Allow:1, Disclose: 1, Cache:1, a URI's is registered.

```
 CREATE PROCEDURE [Auth].[Authorize]
  @Router nvarchar(64),
  @Realm nvarchar(64),
  @Action nvarchar(64),
  @URI nvarchar(256),
  @Match nvarchar(64) = NULL,
  @SessionID bigint,
  @AuthProvider nvarchar(64),
  @AuthMethod nvarchar(64),
  @AuthID nvarchar(64),
  @AuthRole nvarchar(64),
  @TransportPeer nvarchar(64),
  @TransportType nvarchar(64),
  @TransportProtocol nvarchar(64),
  @TransportUserAgent nvarchar(256) = NULL,
  @TransportForwardedFor nvarchar(64) = NULL,
  @F5AuthenticatedDN nvarchar(256) = NULL,
  @F5AuthenticatedClient nvarchar(64) = NULL,
  @Groups GroupsType READONLY
AS

  SELECT
    CAST(
      CASE
        WHEN
          COUNT(*) > 0 AND
          COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN pp.IsAllowed = 0 THEN 1 END) = 0
        THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END
      AS bit) AS Allow,
    CAST(1 AS bit) AS Disclose,
    CAST(1 AS bit) AS Cache
  FROM Auth.Permissions AS pm
  JOIN WAMP.MessageTypes AS mt ON pm.MessageTypeID = mt.ID
  JOIN Auth.PrincipalPermissions AS pp ON pm.ID = pp.PermissionID
  JOIN Auth.Principals AS pr ON pp.PrincipalID = pr.ID
  JOIN Auth.PrincipalTypes AS pt ON pr.PrincipalTypeID = pt.ID
  WHERE
    (

      (pt.Name = 'role' AND pr.Name = 'system')
      /***
      OR
      (pt.Name = 'system' AND pr.Name = 'UATDSG') 
      OR
      (pt.Name = 'group' AND pr.Name IN (SELECT Name FROM @Groups))
      **/
    ) AND
    pr.IsEnabled = 1 AND
    pm.IsEnabled = 1 AND
    mt.Name = 'publish' AND
    'com.XXXX.XX.systems.XXXXX.heartbeat' LIKE pm.URI ESCAPE '\'

RETURN 0
```

I am not very good at stored procedure and this stored procedure.

we have following tables in the database,

```
CREATE TABLE [Auth].[Permissions](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [URI] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
    [MessageTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [nvarchar](512) NULL,
    [IsEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [Auth].[PrincipalPermissions](
    [ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [PrincipalID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [PermissionID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [IsAllowed] [bit] NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [Auth].[Principals](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [PrincipalTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,
    [IsEnabled] [bit] NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [Auth].[PrincipalTypes](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT FOR REPLICATION NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](64) NOT NULL,

CREATE TABLE [WAMP].[MessageTypes](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](32) NOT NULL,


Result Set:

Allow   Disclose    Cache
1       1           1
```

```
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[URI]
      ,[MessageTypeID]
      ,[Description]
      ,[IsEnabled]
FROM [Auth].[Permissions]

ID  URI MessageTypeID   Description IsEnabled
3   %   32  NULL    1
4   %   16  NULL    1
5   %   64  NULL    1
6   %   48  NULL    1
131 com.XXXX.XX.systems.%.heartbeat 16  NULL    1
157 com.XXXX.XX.systems.mfg-%.heartbeat 16  NULL    1
160 com.XXXX.XX.systems.mfg-%.heartbeat 32  NULL    1
161 com.XXXX.XX.systems.%.heartbeat 32  NULL    1


SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[PrincipalID]
      ,[PermissionID]
      ,[IsAllowed]
  FROM [Auth].[PrincipalPermissions]

ID  PrincipalID PermissionID    IsAllowed
1   1   1   1
4   1   9   1
5   1   10  1
6   2   1   1
7   2   12  1
8   2   13  1
9   3   1   1
10  3   3   1
11  3   4   1
12  3   5   1
13  3   6   1
14  5   10  1
15  6   10  1
16  1   15  1
17  1   16  1
18  1   17  1
19  1   18  1
20  1   19  1
21  1   20  1
22  1   21  1
23  1   22  1
24  1   23  1
25  1   24  1
26  1   25  1
27  1   26  1
28  1   27  1
29  1   28  1
30  1   29  1
31  1   30  1
32  1   31  1
33  1   32  1
34  1   33  1
35  1   34  1
36  1   35  1
40  4   39  1
42  7   40  1
47  1   42  1
48  2   43  1
49  1   45  1
50  1   44  1
51  8   38  1
52  6   46  1
53  6   47  1
55  6   1   1
57  5   50  1
58  5   51  1
59  5   41  1
60  7   41  1
61  9   41  1
62  7   52  1
63  7   51  1
64  4   53  1
65  7   54  1
66  10  55  1
67  11  1   1
68  6   38  1
69  6   56  1
70  8   47  1
71  12  56  1
72  12  57  1
73  12  58  1
74  12  59  1
75  12  60  1
76  12  38  1
77  5   61  1
78  5   39  1
80  13  63  1
81  5   63  1
82  14  64  1
83  14  52  1
84  7   65  1
85  7   39  1
86  15  63  1
87  7   63  1
88  10  66  0
89  6   67  1
90  6   68  1
91  12  66  1
92  16  39  1
93  16  63  1
94  17  69  1
95  14  69  1
96  14  39  1
97  7   70  1
98  7   71  1
99  7   69  1
100 6   72  1
101 6   73  1
102 17  74  1
103 12  1   1
104 12  75  1
105 12  76  1
106 3   49  1
107 5   77  1
108 10  63  1
109 10  1   1
110 10  56  1
111 11  3   1
112 11  78  1
113 5   78  1
114 5   79  1
115 11  6   1
116 1   80  1
117 1   81  1
118 2   82  1
119 2   83  1
120 1   84  1
121 1   85  1
122 1   86  1
123 1   87  1
124 1   88  1
125 1   89  1
126 1   90  1
127 1   91  1
128 1   92  1
129 1   93  1
130 1   94  1
131 1   95  1
132 1   96  1
133 1   97  1
134 1   98  1
135 1   99  1
136 1   100 1
137 1   101 1
138 1   102 1
139 1   103 1
140 1   104 1
141 1   105 1
143 18  10  1
144 18  50  1
145 18  51  1
146 18  41  1
147 18  61  1
148 18  39  1
149 18  63  1
150 18  77  1
151 18  78  1
152 18  79  1
153 5   3   1
154 5   4   1
155 5   5   1
156 5   6   1
157 1   107 1
158 4   3   1
159 4   4   1
160 4   5   1
161 4   6   1
162 11  4   1
163 11  5   1
164 20  1   1
165 20  3   1
166 20  78  1
167 20  6   1
168 20  4   1
169 20  5   1
170 19  1   1
171 19  3   1
172 19  78  1
173 19  6   1
174 19  4   1
175 19  5   1
176 19  1   1
177 19  3   1
178 19  78  1
179 19  6   1
180 19  4   1
181 19  5   1
182 21  1   1
183 21  3   1
184 21  78  1
185 21  6   1
186 21  4   1
187 21  5   1
188 1   108 1
189 1   109 1
190 22  1   1
191 22  3   1
192 22  78  1
193 22  6   1
194 22  4   1
195 22  5   1
196 23  1   1
197 23  3   1
198 23  78  1
199 23  6   1
200 23  4   1
201 23  5   1
202 24  1   1
203 24  3   1
204 24  78  1
205 24  6   1
206 24  4   1
207 24  5   1
208 25  1   1
209 25  3   1
210 25  78  1
211 25  6   1
212 25  4   1
213 25  5   1
214 26  1   1
215 26  3   1
216 26  78  1
217 26  6   1
218 26  4   1
219 26  5   1
220 27  1   1
221 27  3   1
222 27  78  1
223 27  6   1
224 27  4   1
225 27  5   1
226 28  1   1
227 28  3   1
228 28  78  1
229 28  6   1
230 28  4   1
231 28  5   1
232 28  1   1
233 28  3   1
234 28  78  1
235 28  6   1
236 28  4   1
237 28  5   1
238 29  1   1
239 29  3   1
240 29  78  1
241 29  6   1
242 29  4   1
243 29  5   1
244 30  1   1
245 30  3   1
246 30  78  1
247 30  6   1
248 30  4   1
249 30  5   1
257 1   106 1
258 1   110 1
259 1   111 1
260 1   112 1
261 33  113 1
262 33  114 1
263 33  115 1
264 1   117 1
265 1   118 1
266 1   119 1
267 1   120 1
268 1   121 1
269 1   122 1
270 1   123 1
271 1   124 1
272 1   125 1
273 1   126 1
274 1   127 1
275 1   128 1
276 1   129 1
277 1   130 1
278 1   131 1
279 1   132 1
280 1   133 1
281 1   134 1
282 1   135 1
283 1   136 1
284 1   137 1
285 1   138 1
286 1   139 1
287 1   140 1
288 1   141 1
289 1   142 1
290 1   143 1
291 1   144 1
292 1   145 1
293 1   146 1
294 1   147 1
295 1   148 1
296 1   149 1
297 1   150 1
298 1   151 1
299 1   152 1
300 1   153 1
301 1   154 1
302 1   155 1
303 1   156 1
304 4   117 1
305 4   118 1
306 4   119 1
307 4   120 1
308 4   121 1
309 4   122 1
310 4   123 1
311 4   124 1
312 4   125 1
313 4   126 1
314 4   127 1
315 4   128 1
316 4   129 1
317 4   130 1
318 4   131 1
319 4   132 1
320 4   133 1
321 4   134 1
322 4   135 1
323 4   136 1
324 4   137 1
325 4   138 1
326 4   139 1
327 4   140 1
328 4   141 1
329 4   142 1
330 4   143 1
331 4   144 1
332 4   145 1
333 4   146 1
334 4   147 1
335 4   148 1
336 4   149 1
337 4   150 1
338 4   151 1
339 4   152 1
340 4   153 1
341 4   154 1
342 4   155 1
343 4   156 1
344 6   161 1


/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[PrincipalTypeID]
      ,[Name]
      ,[IsEnabled]
  FROM [Auth].[Principals]

ID  PrincipalTypeID Name    IsEnabled
1   3   system  1
2   3   user    1
3   3   service 1
35  4   ManufacturingSystem 1


SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[Name]
FROM [Auth].[PrincipalTypes]
ID  Name
2   group
3   role
4   system
1   user

/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT TOP (1000) [ID]
      ,[Name]
  FROM [WAMP].[MessageTypes]

ID  Name
3   abort
5   authenticate
48  call
49  cancel
4   challenge
8   error
36  event
6   goodbye
1   hello
69  interrupt
68  invocation
16  publish
17  published
64  register
65  registered
50  result
32  subscribe
33  subscribed
66  unregister
67  unregistered
34  unsubscribe
35  unsubscribed
2   welcome
70  yield
```

Comment: oops I did not realized that I had that up, when I am  trying to remove it, ST OFL tells me your post mostly looks like code, add more details.

Comment: What would be useful would be some sample data with your expected output.

Comment: I'm confused - with your sample data and your code I get Allow = 0